# Too much "Restart and Update"

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, reboot

I recently reinstalled windows 8.1 64bit and when it finished "Restart and Update", if i go to "Power" again options appears "Restart and Update" again...

I guess it could happen if per example it do not finish updating or if I shutdown the computer before it finishes, but it is NOT the case...

Why always appears Restart and Update, since I updated very recently (update, then when power on, I go to restart 5 or 10 minutes later, and appear "Restart and Update" again).

Comment: After every reboot did you open Windows Update and confirm that no new updates have been found? Otherwise it's simply a case of new updates being installed repeatedly.

Comment: Be cause the updates are not fully installed.  If you always update on Patch Tuesday you won't run into this problem more then twice a month.